# Zend multidb connection is failing

Tags: zend-framework

Hi I am trying to connect two databases in my zend framework application.

Following is my databalse setting in local.ini file.

```
resources.multidb.core.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.multidb.core.params.host = "hostname"
resources.multidb.core.params.username = "root"
resources.multidb.core.params.password = "pwd"
resources.multidb.core.params.dbname = "coredb"
resources.multidb.core.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

resources.multidb.app.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.multidb.app.params.host = "hostname"
resources.multidb.app.params.username = "roor"
resources.multidb.app.params.password = "iamroot123"
resources.multidb.app.params.dbname = "appdb"
resources.multidb.app.isDefaultTableAdapter = false
```

And my code in bootstarp is as follows.

```
public function _initDbRegistry()
{
    $this->bootstrap('multidb');
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    Zend_Registry::set('dbCore', $resource->getDb('core'));
    Zend_Registry::set('dbOlap', $resource->getDb('app'));
}
```

But when i am trying to access my application i am getting the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Configuration array must have a key for 'dbname' that names the database instance' in C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php:287 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(183): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->_checkRequiredOptions(Array) #1 C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend\Db.php(270): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array) #2 C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend\Application\Resource\Multidb.php(99): Zend_Db::factory('pdo_mysql', Array) #3 C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(683): Zend_Application_Resource_Multidb->init() #4 C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(626): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('multidb') #5 C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(586): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #6 C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend\Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Boo in C:\xampp\zend\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php on line 287
```

I am not able to understand what is going wrong. Can someone help me? Also please let me know how i should use the db objects in my model class.

Many thanks.

Comment: Finally i figured out the issue. I should not use params anymore. 

But how come this works for others and in all tutorials and docs the example are showing wiih params in config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looking at the documentation [Multidb Example #14](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb) you application.ini may be incorrect try this (remove: params):

```
resources.multidb.core.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.multidb.core.host = "hostname"
resources.multidb.core.username = "root"
resources.multidb.core.password = "pwd"
resources.multidb.core.dbname = "coredb"
resources.multidb.core.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

resources.multidb.app.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.multidb.app.host = "hostname"
resources.multidb.app.username = "roor"
resources.multidb.app.password = "iamroot123"
resources.multidb.app.dbname = "appdb"
resources.multidb.app.isDefaultTableAdapter = false
```

Comment: thats correct. I already figured it. However many thanks for your suggestion and time.